# Why is my Bash while-loop broken?

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am having a problem with my script. I am trying to read a variable (just like i would in C) and then use that in the counter for the loop. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " How many times?"
read $Read
while [ $Read >1 ];
do 
echo "This is my first script"
Read=$(($Read-1))
done
```

By my logic this program should print the number of times in *Read* because I am decreasing the variable counter. This is not happening. Would you please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: Whitespace is important. Using correct operators is important. `[ $foo >1 ]` is the same as `[ $foo ] >1`, both of which also differ from `[ "$foo" ] >1`.

Comment: ...now, if you wanted a _numeric_ context, you could use `(( Read > 1 ))`, and *that* would actually do what you wanted.

Comment: On a related note, `Read=$(($Read-1))` would be more tersely written as `(( Read-- ))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` takes the *name* of a variable, without the dollar sign.

```
read Read
```

It's not technically an error to use the dollar sign; it just probably isn't what you meant. The parameter would be expanded, and its value would be used as the name of the variable that `read` sets. For example:

```
$ foo=bar
$ read $foo <<< 5
$ echo $bar
5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p 'How many times? ' times
while [[ $times -ge 1 ]]; do
    echo "This is my first script."
    let times-=1
done
```

Comment: This is an... interesting mix of modern and older syntax. Why use `-ge` if you're willing to use bashisms that guarantee that you could also write `while (( times >= 1 ))`?

Comment: CodeGnome, thank you for that, it worked. Also you all please do not feel i was simply looking for any easy answer, i have implemented a lot of research on this. I have not asked a question is this forum to simply get a "solution" i wanted to get an "explanation " as well. My mind was struck in C language rules, i guess they cannot be adopted in shell scripting. Would anyone be kind enough to tell me what is the mistake i have made in my code ? I was thinking $Read stores some values and it should be good.

Comment: @BharatNT2IE Your original code had LOTS of problems. Run it through http://www.shellcheck.net to get a non-exhaustive list of things that were wrong and suggestions on how to fix them.

Comment: @CodeGnome thank you very much, that you for you help and also that is exactly what i was looking for a reference thank you.